# Heroku-18 w/ .NET Core GDI+: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be found

Tags: heroku, .net-core

Since upgrading from Heroku-16 to Heroku-18 stack, my .NET Core 2.2 App that references `System.Drawing.Common` to use GDI+ throws the error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
--->System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgdiplus': The specified module could not be found.
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.FunctionWrapper `1.get_Delegate()
 at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdiplusStartup(IntPtr& token, StartupInput& input, StartupOutput& output)
 at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
```

This is because `libc6-dev` is not installed ([see this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2746)). I'm using [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install both `libgdiplus` and `libc6-dev`), but it appears that the package is **no longer available at runtime on Heroku-18**, only at build time ([see this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages)).

From the build log:

```
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for libc6-dev
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        Reinstallation of libc6-dev is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
remote:        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Reverting back to Heroku-16 solves the issue.

How can this I make this work on the Heroku-18 stack?? Anyone found a way?

Comment: _just for the record_, My problem has been solved by upgrading the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/) to v5.0.0. The project is based on .NET Core 3.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

From Heroku support:

> I am really sorry for the trouble but it will not be possible in my view. This package libc6-dev2.27-3ubuntu1 means that the package is available only at build time, but not at runtime. Moreover if you have some requirement you can check https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/eugeneotto/heroku-buildpack-secp256k1 but this is not officially supported buildpack and we do not provide support for this.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3.x, together with the latest version of System.Drawing.Common, contain fixes which remove the dependency on libc6-dev.

If installing libc6-dev is not possible, you can try to:

- Upgrade to .NET Core 3.0
- Upgrade to libgdiplus 4.6.0 or later (I'd recommend 4.7.0)

Comment: That's certainly worth a try!
(I'm having issues upgrading to .NET Core 3 because of some EF breaking changes, but that's unrelated. As soon as I can fix those, I'll try it to confirm.)